# Can't add references in Visual Studio 2017 (no reference node)

Tags: visual-studio, reference

So I want to start learning C#, but I am having some trouble using Visual Studio 2017 (I've tried the Community Edition and the Professional Edition). The problem is that whenever I create a Console Application solution, There is no reference node in the solution explorer. When I installed Visual Studio on my laptop, the node was there. Does anyone know if there is some setting to get the reference node to appear?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be in the solution explorer view, but instead you are in the folder view. Try to click the button on the top that looks like a window and a folder and this will display your reference nodes. Hope this helps